# AWS ALB return an empty page when used with ECS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I am working on containerizing one react app & provision it using ECS cluster with alb.
**Everything looks great but whenever I accessing the ALB DNS in the browser it returns an empty page with 2 words only "react app"**
I checked health check all the backend instances are healthy and returning `200 code`.

*I have used the ec2 instances IP address in the browser and the page loaded completely.*

It seem issue with the alb, why not loaded the complete page

Comment: what is the health status of target group in your ec2 instance?

Comment: its shown healthy, even i tried another react app same results , when you open it from EC2(paste the ip address in the browzer) working fine and when i past on any browzer the dns name of the loadbalencer its shown empty page with 2 words"reack app" on the header.

Comment: Can you show your ALB's listeners and forwarding rules?

Comment: Hi Stefan , rules are IF
1 if Path is/  THEN
Forward to
ecs-zero-zero: 1 (100%)
Group-level stickiness: Off

Answer (score 0):

It should be a problem on how you have configured the DockerFile.
You would have added some default route to nginx configuration which displays 'react app'.

To debug, please try to run the DockerFile from your local using *Docker Desktop* and see if you are able to browse the react app.

If it works fine in your local then for sure 100% it'll work in ECS without any problem.